# how to get date from jquery date picker using droppable

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, datepicker

I am trying to get date from Jquery ui date-picker by dropping some events on the calendar cell.

as soon i drop some events on the calendar, it should show an alert displaying the date on which i have dropped the event.

```
$(".ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr td").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        // $("#datepicker").datepicker._selectDay('#datepicker',2,2012, this);
        alert('Event added <show dropped date>#####');
    }
});
```

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you instantiate the droppable on drag start, you could simply fire a click event on drop.

The dropped date will then be accessible through the usual `getDate` method.

```
$(".event").draggable({
    start: function () {
        $(".ui-datepicker-calendar td").droppable({
            drop: function() {
                $(this).click();
                var theDate = $(".datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
                alert( "Event Created on " + theDate.toDateString() );
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I did have a bit of trouble getting the draggable itself to act nice with such small drop zones, so I had to position the cursor using `cursorAt`.  Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mj7dd/5/) to see.

Comment: Hey thank you so much.After dropping the image it is placing on the calendar only.it needs to go back to the original position.i am giving revert: true also .At that time dragging is not working.Please help me on this

Comment: I used `helper:clone` instead of `revert:true` and that seems to work ok.  What browser are you using?  Have a  look at the jsFiddle I linked to see if it works for you.